# Google oAuth login Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, google-authentication

I made a application with a reigster form. I adapted firebase realtime database. bu I want to let users sign in with their google account too. I tried this link https://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/
but it didn't worked.
any idea how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: try putting some code examples of what you tried and show the actual error. that will make this a much better question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SCS0T4pKk7bet81A4F-VH2CW7rGdgSnK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Not like this. the editor has options to put your code right there along  with the question. if you have to share, put it in a code sandbox or github (like many code files). dont link to google drive. that is not the best way.